# Darken the screen except one gridview item in Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am trying to find a way to darken the entire screen except for a specific gridview item (in order to draw attention to this specific item).

I have been able to darken the whole screen by putting a black partially transperant view in front of the app content like this:

```
<FrameLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <GridView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/gridView"
            android:numColumns="2"/>
    <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="#88000000" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Unfortunately I cannot come up with a way to make one gridview item not get darker. Can anyone help me out here?

Comment: Give the GridView a background color as well.

Comment: Inflate the gridview position view in a custom dialog which maintains its x, y position on screen and 'darkens' the rest of the layout.

Comment: @Mark Keen This seems like a great idea. I will try it and if it works I might ask you to add that as an answer.

Comment: @Mark Keen It works! Please add that as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: Well you did all the hard work getting it to work! I've added the answer - maybe you could add your implementation. Glad you got the result you were looking for.

Comment: @Fredrik: Can you put your implementation of Mark's suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Inflate the gridview position view in a custom dialog which maintains its x, y position on screen and 'darkens' the rest of the layout.

Answer (score 0):

Could this also work? Set a background color to whatever you want and in getView return transparent image to all grid items except the one you want to display.